# Hacer una consulta con LEFT JOIN primera coincidencia

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Para poner en contexto, estoy creando una función para exportar los datos que tengo en unas tablas de Access a ficheros `.csv`, para ello he creado distintas consultas que luego exporto.

Tengo una consulta de clientes, la cual tiene una tabla de clientes, y otra tabla de números de teléfono. No todos los clientes tienen un número de teléfono, pero hay algunos que tienen más de un número de teléfono.

Lo que necesito, es que solo me coja el primer número de teléfono en caso de que tenga más de uno, ya que sino, en la consulta me escribe más de una línea por cada cliente, y necesito que máximo tenga una línea por cliente.

La consulta que tengo ahora:

```
SELECT distinct(dbo_clientes.CODIGO) AS Código, dbo_clientes.NOMBRE AS Nombre, Replace(Format(dbo_clientes.F_ALTA,'yyyy-mm-dd'),'-','') AS [Fecha de Alta], "" AS Nacimiento, dbo_clientes.CIF AS DNI, dbo_telf_cli.TELEFONO AS [Teléfono Fijo], "" AS [Teléfono Móvil], "" AS FAX, "" AS [Tipo de Vía], dbo_clientes.Direccion AS Calle, "" AS Número, "" AS Piso, "" AS Puerta, dbo_clientes.POBLACION AS Población, dbo_clientes.PROVINCIA AS Provincia, dbo_clientes.CODPOST AS [Código Postal], Replace(dbo_clientes.PAIS,'034','ESP') AS País, dbo_clientes.EMAIL AS eMail, "" AS sexo, "" AS [Estado civil], "" AS Profesión, "" AS Nacionalidad

FROM dbo_clientes LEFT JOIN dbo_telf_cli ON dbo_clientes.CODIGO = dbo_telf_cli.CLIENTE;
```

He intentado poner `GROUP BY dbo_clientes.CODIGO`, pero me salta el siguiente error:

> Su consulta no incluye la expresión especificada 'Nombre' como parte de una función de agregado

Comment: Y esos numeros de telefono, tienen algun orden? o si hay varios agarras cualquiera?

Comment: En caso de que haya mas de uno, me es indiferente cual coger, bien puede ser el primero ya que imagino que simplificaría las cosas

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema en vez de utilizar un Left Join que una todos los registros de la tabla `dbo_telf_cli` con la tabla `dbo_clientes` puedes utilizar un Inner Join.
Prueba a ver si te funciona y me dices.